# How to make li elements fit horizontal and vertical inside a fixed size container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder how to make a list of `li` to auto fit inside a fixed size container.

well here is my idea:

```
<div class="box">
   <ul>
       <li>#1</li>
       <li>#1</li>
       <li>#1</li>
       <li>#1</li>
       <li>#1</li>
       ...
   </ul>
</div>
```

Let's give a fixed size to DIV ".box" - width: 500px; height: 560px;

So how to make all "li" to dynamic change height and width in order to fit inside BOX?

PS 
`li` can be 5 or 11 or even 3 and I want height and width of all `li` to be the same, this is a part of the design

I found this example: http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/3/

But is only works for a horizontal line. In my situation it can be 2 or even 3 raws.

Comment: And how would you figure out how many li's you want for every row?

Comment: Well I guess it must be auto! I know it is possible, some time ago i met such example on the web, it was done with Jquery. And now i cant find it...

Comment: I'm asking for an implementation detail, that can't be "auto". Why should the implementation create a second row?

Answer (score 0):

As to horizontal you can set the ul element css to display type table and the li to display type table-cell

```
ul {display:table; width:100%; height:100%}
li {display:table-cell;}
```

as to the vertical i think you might need to add jQuery to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Set `li` to `display: block` and use [some of these css reset files](http://www.cssreset.com/) to remove margins from `ul`. That will do the trick for horizontal. And for vertical you can do something like this:

```
var containerHeight = parseInt($('.box').css('height'));
var liNum = $('li').length;
var liHeight = Math.floor(containerHeight / liNum);

$('li').css('height', liHeight);
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/vSHYt/1/

Note that in this example I've used border on `li` elements, and the border is added to their height, that is why they fall out of the container `div`. Also, I've used reset for Chrome, if you are using some other browser, maybe you'll see before margin to `ul`. And, of course, if the height of the container box is not divisible by the number of `li`'s, they'll fall few pixels short.